How to retrive billing invoices (payment activities) from business manager via facebook/php-business-sdk or Graph API?
how can i retrive the billing invoices (payment activities) from my business manager account via PHP SDK of Facebook Business or via Graph API?
I would like duplicate the content that i see in page as https://business.facebook.com/billing_hub/payment_activity?asset_id=0000000000&business_id=000000000000&placement=ads_manager&date=00000000_00000000
payment activities on business manager
I have my business account id, my customer adv account id but when i try to retrive che invoices i get the empty response, without any error, but only an empty data.
I am sure that the account has many invoices and payment activities.
I have tried both approaches yet
test via API
test via SDK

I found a partial solution.
To retrive the list of transactions there is an api called {business_account_id}/activities and it work, but when i retrive the transaction ID i can't retrive the invoice PDF.
